# ITO Process with random initial position

Tags: probability-or-statistics, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to define an ITO process with random initial state but its only drawing once an uses it for all paths. Here is the code:

```
proc[\[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_] := 
 ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[
     t] == \[Mu] \[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma] \[DifferentialD]w[t], 
  x[t], {x, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2]]}, t, 
  w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
```

Any suggestions how to make this work? Thank you in advance.

e

Comment: I'll ponder this, my initial impression is no, since the process is evaluated before the ensemble is generated. Would simply generating a table of the random functions and then getting paths/etc. from those be a problem?

Comment: Yes but I was hoping there would be a trick ...

Comment: See my (writing now) answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is directly possible - the process is evaluated before the random paths are generated. I'll ponder further, but if you want the same effect, try something like this:

```
ensemble1 = TemporalData[Table[RandomFunction[proc[1, 1], {0, 1}], 10]];
```

This will give you the same structure as

```
ensemble2 = RandomFunction[proc[1, 1], {0, 1},10]
```

that is, both examples give an ensemble of 10, but the former will give you the random starting positions:

```
Row[ListLinePlot[#, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {ensemble1, ensemble2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great. If you think of better solution I would be very interested to see it. Thank you.